# SQL Developer - save result form many SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to run many select from one script like :

```
SELECT * FROM table_01;
SELECT * FROM table_02;
..
SELECT * FROM table_xx;
```

How to save result for all **`SELECT`** in `SQL Developer` ?

Comment: I don't understand. There are many tables in your database. Probably with different columns, for otherwise why would it be separate tables? And you want to `select *` from each table and store the result? But the result is stored. In the table. So, what is it you are actually asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple option is to **spool** result into a file. Here's how:

[image]